# accessing heroku database with hibernate eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, postgresql, heroku

I'm new to hibernate and heroku. I created a database on heroku and trying to access database with my eclipse plugin - hibernate to generate POJO classes. I'm getting error like - "Reading Schema error:Getting database metadata". I checked username, password, database name ..everything seems to be correct and I couldn't connect with PGAdmin tool ( to access Postgres database).

Can you help me in connecting heroku database with eclipse hibernate plugin ?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
 <hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">xxxxxx</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://xxxxx:5432/xxxxx</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">xxxxxxx</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">xxxxxx</property>
</session-factory>
```

Any help is appreciated !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found solution for my question. I have to use ssl connection, so the url is:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://xxxx-host-xxxx:5432/xxx-database-xxx?sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory&amp;ssl=true</property>
```

Comment: takes around 3 mins for the connection to establish, any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Install Heroku Toolbelt and then type `heroku config`. Take each part of the DATABASE_URL in this form: postgres://username:password@host:port/dbname

This works fine with PGAdmin and should work with any other Postgres-compatible tool. Note that Heroku often uses non-standard ports.